# GitHub doesn't show plotly charts

Tags: github, plotly, plotly-python

How I can make plotly chart visible at Github.
Unfortunately Github shows nothing when I use px plots.

```
fig = px.choropleth(data_frame = df22,
                    locations= 'Country',
                    locationmode='country names',
                    color= 'Happiness Score',
                    hover_name= "Country",
                    color_continuous_scale= 'RdYlGn',
                    width=1200,
                    height=600,)
fig.show()
```

I can see plot at VSCode.
[image: VSCode]
GitHub shows nothing.
[image: GitHub]

I've tried to use fig.show("png"), but it doesn't work

Comment: Where have you put this code? Do you want to put the image in a readme or something? Just run something like `fig.write_image("fig.png")` in your own environment (vscode or whatever). Then you should have a png in your project folder. Upload the image on github.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/

Comment: This code in my notebook(.ipynb file) and I make there some analysis, visualize results and write conclusions . So I would like to see there (at GitHub) at least static plot (interactive would be perfect)